# Post-hoc analyses with a synthetic control?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, ab-test, false-discovery-rate, marketing

When running a traditional hypothesis test, it's common to "break out" the result by sub-groups using various post-hoc methods that control for multiple comparisons, such as the False Discovery Rate.

When running a test using a synthetic control, can you "break out" the result by different sub-groups as well?

Comment: What is a "synthetic control"?

Comment: Synthetic controls are an alternative to traditional control groups.  Basically, you create a response model for a time period prior to the introduction of a policy or marketing intervention.  As long as the intervention doesn't alter the inputs to the response model, you can use the response model to generate a synthetic control after the intervention.  There are 2 R packages for this, a frequentist one - http://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/synthpage.html - and a Bayesian one - http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2014/09/causalimpact-new-open-source-package.html.